# I have to set values from a single row result into multiple lines in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I achieve this with SQL in oracle without creating stored procedure?

I Just have one row in COUNT_INFO table. Here is the result when I run select * from COUNT_INFO.

Data Set:

```
ID          DATE        DELETED_COUNT   UPDATED_COUNT   ERROR_COUNT
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1        10-AUG-17          500             450             50
```

I need to convert this data set into something like following where the counts can be on different rows with associated column names.

Desired Result:

```
CNT         STATUS      DT
---------------------------------
500     DELETED 10-AUG-17
450     UPDATED     10-AUG-17
50      ERROR       10-AUG-17
```

Comment: What do the counts in the source data have to do with the counts in the results?

Comment: For almost any question you ask, there are different answers (different tools available) depending on your Oracle version. Don't guess if you are not 100% sure; run `select * from v$version` and see what it says. What you need to do in this problem is to `UNPIVOT` the data. Do a search for it - you will find different answers depending on Oracle version.